# Simple Minesweeper using OpenGL / GLUT

Tags: c++, opengl, minesweeper

I'm trying to make minesweeper similar to windows 3.1 minesweeper by using OpenGL / GLUT. The game still in early stage but playable. I would like to know, how can I improve it.

EDIT 1:
i added additional draw functions and fixed drawing order when player step on mine tile.

here image for latest update:

[image]

Edit 2:
i have added timer class for animating when player is win or lose to demo and fixed index coordinate from mouse input. also, i added option to restart game at any time by click on game icon "smiley face"

Edit 3):
added drawing functions for primitive shapes (rect, circle) to avoid duplicated.
added Color for readability.
finally, anti-alias is working perfectly under GLUT context.

Edit 4):
removed the old window time with the c++11 std::chrono

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <chrono>

#include <gl/glut.h>


enum { MINE = 9 };
enum { TILE_SIZE = 20 };
enum { MARGIN = 40 };
enum { PADDING = 10 };
enum { BOARD_SIZE = 9 };
enum { MINE_COUNT = 10 };

enum Color {
    RED,
    DARKRED,
    BLUE,
    DARKBLUE,
    GREEN,
    DARKGREEN,
    CYAN,
    DARKCYAN,
    YELLOW,
    DARKYELLOW,
    WHITE,
    MAGENTA,
    BLACK,
    DARKGRAY,
    LIGHTGRAY,
    ULTRALIGHTGRAY
};

static const struct
{
    float r, g, b;
} colors[] =
{
    { 1, 0, 0 },// red
    { 0.5f, 0, 0 },// dark red

    { 0, 0, 1 }, // blue
    { 0, 0, 0.5f }, // dark blue

    { 0, 1, 0 }, // green
    { 0, 0.5f, 0 }, // dark green

    { 0, 1, 1 }, // cyan
    { 0, 0.5f, 0.5f }, // dark  cyan

    { 1, 1, 0 },//yellow
    { 0.5f, 0.5f, 0 },//dark yellow

    { 1, 1, 1 },// White
    { 1, 0, 1 }, // magenta

    { 0, 0, 0 }, // black
    { 0.25, 0.25, 0.25 }, // dark gray
    { 0.5, 0.5, 0.5 }, // light gray
    { 0.75, 0.75, 0.75 }, // ultra-light gray

};

class  Clock
{
    typedef std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> time_point;
public:
    Clock()
        : m_startTime(getCurrentTime())
        , m_lastTime()
    {
    }

    double getElapsedTime() const
    {
        std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed = getCurrentTime() - m_startTime;
        return elapsed.count();
    }

    double restart()
    {
        time_point now = getCurrentTime();
        std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed = now - m_startTime;
        m_startTime = now;

        return elapsed.count();
    }

    static time_point getCurrentTime()
    {
        return std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    }

private:
    time_point m_startTime;
    time_point m_lastTime;

}game_clock;

struct cell
{
    int type;
    bool flag;
    bool open;
};

cell board[BOARD_SIZE*BOARD_SIZE];
int death;
int width;
int height;
bool clicked;
int num_opened;


int rand_int(int low, int high)
{
    static std::default_random_engine re{ std::random_device{}() };
    using Dist = std::uniform_int_distribution<int>;
    static Dist uid{};
    return uid(re, Dist::param_type{ low,high });
}

void drawRect(int x, int y, float width, float height, const Color& color = LIGHTGRAY, bool outline = true)
{
    glColor3f(colors[color].r, colors[color].g, colors[color].b);
    glBegin(outline ? GL_LINE_STRIP : GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);
    {
        glVertex2i(x + 0 * width, y + 0 * height);
        glVertex2i(x + 1 * width, y + 0 * height);
        glVertex2i(x + 1 * width, y + 1 * height);
        glVertex2i(x + 0 * width, y + 1 * height);
    }
    glEnd();
}

void drawCircle(int cx, int cy, float radius, const Color& color = LIGHTGRAY, bool outline = true)
{
    glColor3f(colors[color].r, colors[color].g, colors[color].b);
    glBegin(outline ? GL_LINE_LOOP : GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);
    for (int i = 0; i <= 32; i++) {
        float angle = 2 * 3.14159 * i / 32.0f;
        float x = radius * cosf(angle);
        float y = radius * sinf(angle);
        glVertex2f(x+cx, y+cy);
    }
    glEnd();
}

void drawFlag(int x, int y)
{
    glColor3f(colors[BLACK].r, colors[BLACK].g, colors[BLACK].b);
    x = (x*TILE_SIZE) + PADDING + 6;
    y = (y*TILE_SIZE) + PADDING + 3;

    //platform
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    {
        glVertex2i(x + 0, y + 2);
        glVertex2i(x + 9, y + 2);
        glVertex2i(x + 9, y + 3);
        glVertex2i(x + 7, y + 3);
        glVertex2i(x + 7, y + 4);
        glVertex2i(x + 3, y + 4);
        glVertex2i(x + 3, y + 3);
        glVertex2i(x + 0, y + 3);
    }
    glEnd();

    //mast
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    {
        glVertex2i(x + 4, y + 4);
        glVertex2i(x + 4, y + 7);
    }
    glEnd();

    //flag
    glColor3f(colors[RED].r, colors[RED].g, colors[RED].b);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    {
        glVertex2i(x + 5, y + 7);
        glVertex2i(x + 5, y + 12);
        glVertex2i(x + 0, y + 9);
    }
    glEnd();
}

void drawMine(int x, int y, bool dead)
{
    if (dead)
    {
        drawRect(x*TILE_SIZE + PADDING, y*TILE_SIZE + PADDING, TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE, RED, false);
    }


    x = (x*TILE_SIZE) + PADDING + 4;
    y = (y*TILE_SIZE) + PADDING + 4;

    //spikes
    glColor3f(colors[BLACK].r, colors[BLACK].g, colors[BLACK].b);
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    {
        glVertex2i(x + 5, y - 1);
        glVertex2i(x + 5, y + 12);

        glVertex2i(x - 1, y + 5);
        glVertex2i(x + 12, y + 5);

        glVertex2i(x + 1, y + 1);
        glVertex2i(x + 10, y + 10);

        glVertex2i(x + 1, y + 10);
        glVertex2i(x + 10, y + 1);
    }
    glEnd();

    //ball
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    {
        glVertex2i(x + 3, y + 1);
        glVertex2i(x + 1, y + 4);
        glVertex2i(x + 1, y + 7);
        glVertex2i(x + 3, y + 10);
        glVertex2i(x + 8, y + 10);
        glVertex2i(x + 10, y + 7);
        glVertex2i(x + 10, y + 4);
        glVertex2i(x + 8, y + 1);
    }
    glEnd();

    //shine
    drawRect(x+3, y+5, 2, 2, WHITE, false);
}

void drawNum(int x, int y, int v)
{
    switch (v)
    {
    case 1:
        glColor3f(colors[BLUE].r, colors[BLUE].g, colors[BLUE].b);
        break;
    case 2:
        glColor3f(colors[GREEN].r, colors[GREEN].g, colors[GREEN].b);
        break;
    case 3:
        glColor3f(colors[RED].r, colors[RED].g, colors[RED].b);
        break;
    case 4:
        glColor3f(colors[DARKBLUE].r, colors[DARKBLUE].g, colors[DARKBLUE].b);
        break;
    case 5:
        glColor3f(colors[DARKRED].r, colors[DARKRED].g, colors[DARKRED].b);
        break;
    case 6:
        glColor3f(colors[DARKYELLOW].r, colors[DARKYELLOW].g, colors[DARKYELLOW].b);
        break;
    case 7:
        glColor3f(colors[CYAN].r, colors[CYAN].g, colors[CYAN].b);
        break;
    case 8:
        glColor3f(colors[DARKCYAN].r, colors[DARKCYAN].g, colors[DARKCYAN].b);
        break;
    }
    glRasterPos2i((x + 0)*TILE_SIZE + PADDING + 6, (y + 0)*TILE_SIZE + PADDING + 5);
    glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_9_BY_15, '0' + v);
}


void drawFrame(float x, float y, float width, float height, bool doubleFrame = true)
{

    glColor3f(colors[WHITE].r, colors[WHITE].g, colors[WHITE].b);
    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
    {
        glVertex2f((x + 0) + 0 * width, (y - 0) + 0 * height);
        glVertex2f((x - 0) + 0 * width, (y - 1) + 1 * height);
        glVertex2f((x - 1) + 1 * width, (y - 1) + 1 * height);
        glVertex2f((x - 2) + 1 * width, (y - 2) + 1 * height);
        glVertex2f((x + 1) + 0 * width, (y - 2) + 1 * height);
        glVertex2f((x + 1) + 0 * width, (y + 1) + 0 * height);
    }
    glEnd();

    glColor3f(colors[LIGHTGRAY].r, colors[LIGHTGRAY].g, colors[LIGHTGRAY].b);
    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
    {
        glVertex2f((x - 2) + 1 * width, (y - 2) + 1 * height);
        glVertex2f((x - 2) + 1 * width, (y + 1) + 0 * height);
        glVertex2f((x + 1) + 0 * width, (y + 1) + 0 * height);
        glVertex2f((x - 0) + 0 * width, (y - 0) + 0 * height);
        glVertex2f((x - 1) + 1 * width, (y - 0) + 0 * height);
        glVertex2f((x - 1) + 1 * width, (y - 1) + 1 * height);
    }
    glEnd();

    if (!doubleFrame) return;

    width = width - 2 * PADDING;
    height = height - 2 * PADDING;


    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
    {
        glVertex2f((x - 0 + PADDING) + 0 * width, (y + PADDING - 0) + 0 * height);
        glVertex2f((x - 0 + PADDING) + 0 * width, (y + PADDING - 1) + 1 * height);
        glVertex2f((x - 1 + PADDING) + 1 * width, (y + PADDING - 1) + 1 * height);
        glVertex2f((x - 2 + PADDING) + 1 * width, (y + PADDING - 2) + 1 * height);
        glVertex2f((x + 1 + PADDING) + 0 * width, (y + PADDING - 2) + 1 * height);
        glVertex2f((x + 1 + PADDING) + 0 * width, (y + PADDING + 1) + 0 * height);
    }
    glEnd();
    glColor3f(colors[WHITE].r, colors[WHITE].g, colors[WHITE].b);

    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
    {
        glVertex2i((x + PADDING - 2) + 1 * width, (y + PADDING - 2) + 1 * height);
        glVertex2i((x + PADDING - 2) + 1 * width, (y + PADDING + 1) + 0 * height);
        glVertex2i((x + PADDING + 1) + 0 * width, (y + PADDING + 1) + 0 * height);
        glVertex2i((x + PADDING - 0) + 0 * width, (y + PADDING - 0) + 0 * height);
        glVertex2i((x + PADDING - 1) + 1 * width, (y + PADDING - 0) + 0 * height);
        glVertex2i((x + PADDING - 1) + 1 * width, (y + PADDING - 1) + 1 * height);
    }
    glEnd();
}

void drawClosedDim(int x, int y)
{
    drawFrame(x *TILE_SIZE + PADDING, y*TILE_SIZE + PADDING, TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE, false);
}

void drawOpenDim(int x, int y)
{
    drawRect(x*TILE_SIZE + PADDING, y*TILE_SIZE + PADDING, TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE);
}

void drawUpperFrame(int x = 0, int y = 0)
{
    static const float upper_frame_outter_width = width;
    static const float upper_frame_outter_height = 2 * MARGIN;
    static const float offset = height - upper_frame_outter_height;

    drawFrame(0, offset, upper_frame_outter_width, upper_frame_outter_height);
}

void drawLowerFrame(int x = 0, int y = 0)
{
    static const float lower_frame_outter_size = width;
    drawFrame(0, 0, lower_frame_outter_size, lower_frame_outter_size);
}

void drawIcon(int x = 0, int y = 0)
{
    static const float icon_size = 2 * TILE_SIZE;
    if (clicked)
    {
        int x = 0, y = 0;
        static const float cx = (width - icon_size) / 2.0f;
        static const float cy = (height - MARGIN) - icon_size / 2.0f;
        drawRect(cx, cy, 2 * TILE_SIZE, 2 * TILE_SIZE, ULTRALIGHTGRAY, false);

        if (game_clock.getElapsedTime() > 0.25) {
            clicked = false;
            game_clock.restart();
        }
    }

    drawFrame((width - icon_size) / 2.0f, (height - MARGIN) - icon_size / 2.0f, icon_size, icon_size, false);

    static const float cx = width / 2.0f;
    static const float cy = (height - MARGIN);

    // face
    drawCircle(x + cx, y + cy, TILE_SIZE*0.707f, YELLOW, false);
    drawCircle(x + cx, y + cy, TILE_SIZE*0.707f, DARKGRAY);

    // eyes
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    glVertex2f(-4.707 + cx, 1.707 + cy);
    glVertex2f(4.707 + cx, 1.707 + cy);
    glEnd();

    // mouth
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    {
        glVertex2f(-3.707 + cx, -8.707 + cy);
        glVertex2f(3.707 + cx, -8.707 + cy);
    }
    glEnd();
}

int index(int x, int y)
{
    return x + (y*BOARD_SIZE);
}

bool isOpen(int x, int y)
{
    return board[index(x, y)].open;
}


int getType(int x, int y)
{
    return board[index(x, y)].type;
}

void setType(int x, int y, int v)
{
    board[index(x, y)].type = v;
}

bool isMine(int x, int y)
{
    if (x < 0 || y < 0 || x > BOARD_SIZE - 1 || y > BOARD_SIZE - 1)
        return false;

    if (getType(x, y) == MINE)
        return true;
    return false;
}

int calcMine(int x, int y)
{
    return isMine(x - 1, y - 1)
        + isMine(x, y - 1)
        + isMine(x + 1, y - 1)
        + isMine(x - 1, y)
        + isMine(x + 1, y)
        + isMine(x - 1, y + 1)
        + isMine(x, y + 1)
        + isMine(x + 1, y + 1);
}

bool isFlag(int x, int y)
{
    return board[index(x, y)].flag;
}

bool gameOver()
{
    return death != -1;
}

bool isDead(int x, int y)
{
    return death == index(x, y);
}

bool hasWon()
{
    return num_opened == MINE_COUNT;
}

void openMines(bool open = true)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < BOARD_SIZE; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < BOARD_SIZE; x++) {
            if (isMine(x, y))
                board[index(x, y)].open = open;
        }
    }
}

void openCell(int x, int y)
{
    if (x < 0 || y < 0 || y > BOARD_SIZE - 1 || x > BOARD_SIZE - 1)
        return;
    if (isOpen(x, y))
        return;
    num_opened--;
    board[index(x, y)].open = true;
    if (isMine(x, y))
    {
        death = index(x, y);
        openMines();
        return;
    }

    if (getType(x, y) == 0)
    {
        openCell(x - 1, y + 1);
        openCell(x, y + 1);
        openCell(x + 1, y + 1);
        openCell(x - 1, y);
        openCell(x + 1, y);
        openCell(x - 1, y - 1);
        openCell(x, y - 1);
        openCell(x + 1, y - 1);
    }
}

void toggleFlag(int x, int y)
{
    board[index(x, y)].flag = !isFlag(x, y);
}

void drawOpen(int x, int y, int n, bool dead)
{
    switch (n) {
    case 0:
        drawOpenDim(x, y);
        break;
    case 9:
        if (!dead) {
            drawOpenDim(x, y);
        }
        drawMine(x, y, dead);
        break;
    default:
        drawOpenDim(x, y);
        drawNum(x, y, n);
    }
}

void drawClosed(int x, int y)
{
    drawClosedDim(x, y);
    if (isFlag(x, y))
        drawFlag(x, y);
}

void draw()
{   
    for (int y = 0; y < BOARD_SIZE; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < BOARD_SIZE; x++)
        {
            if (isOpen(x, y))
                drawOpen(x, y, getType(x, y), isDead(x, y));
            else
                drawClosed(x, y);
        }
    }

    if (gameOver() || hasWon()) {
        if (game_clock.getElapsedTime() > 0.25) {
            static int toggle = 1;
            toggle ^= 1;
            openMines(toggle == 0);
            game_clock.restart();
        }
    }
}

bool requestRestart(int x, int y)
{
    return (x >= 3 && x <= 5 && y >= 10 && y <= 12);
}

void init()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < BOARD_SIZE*BOARD_SIZE; i++) {
        board[i].type = 0;
        board[i].flag = false;
        board[i].open = false;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i<MINE_COUNT; i++)
    {
        bool tmp = true;
        do
        {
            int x = rand_int(0, BOARD_SIZE - 1);
            int y = rand_int(0, BOARD_SIZE - 1);
            if (!isMine(x, y))
            {
                tmp = false;
                setType(x, y, MINE);
            }
        } while (tmp);
    }

    for (int y = 0; y < BOARD_SIZE; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < BOARD_SIZE; x++) {
            if (!isMine(x, y)) {
                setType(x, y, calcMine(x, y));
            }
        }
    }

    death = -1;
    clicked = true;
    game_clock.restart();

    num_opened = BOARD_SIZE*BOARD_SIZE;
    glClearColor(0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f, 1.f);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0, width, 0, height, -1.f, 1.f);
    glPointSize(5.0);
    glEnable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH);
    glHint(GL_LINE_SMOOTH_HINT, GL_NICEST);
    glEnable(GL_POINT_SMOOTH);
    glHint(GL_POINT_SMOOTH_HINT, GL_NICEST);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
}

// glut callbacks
void display()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    drawLowerFrame();
    drawUpperFrame();
    drawIcon();
    draw();

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void key(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
    switch (key) {
    case 27: exit(0); break;
    }
    //glutPostRedisplay();
}

void mouse(int b, int s, int x, int y)
{
    x = (x + PADDING) / TILE_SIZE - 1;
    y = (height - y + PADDING) / TILE_SIZE - 1;

    switch (b)
    {
    case GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON:
        if (s == GLUT_DOWN)
        {
            if (requestRestart(x, y))
            {
                init();
            }
            else if (!gameOver() && !hasWon()) {
                openCell(x, y);
            }
        }
        break;
    case GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON:
        if (s == GLUT_DOWN)
        {
            if (gameOver() || hasWon()) break;
            toggleFlag(x, y);
        }
        break;
    }

    //glutPostRedisplay();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    width = BOARD_SIZE*TILE_SIZE + 2 * PADDING;
    height = BOARD_SIZE*TILE_SIZE + 2 * PADDING + 2 * MARGIN;

    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_MULTISAMPLE);
    glutInitWindowSize(width, height);
    glutInitWindowPosition((glutGet(GLUT_SCREEN_WIDTH) - width) / 2, (glutGet(GLUT_SCREEN_HEIGHT) - height) / 2);
    glutCreateWindow("minesweeper");
    glutIdleFunc(display);
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutKeyboardFunc(key);
    glutMouseFunc(mouse);

    init();

    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Foreseeing future reviews: glBegin/end, procedural style, magic constants, C libraries :)

Comment: @Incomputable for magic constants yeah, these numbers came out of my desperate attempt to adjust drawable figures. i sure there is better and efficient way to do it. this is why i post it here. could you please elaborate more about procedural style? is texturing is better candidate?

Comment: I haven't done much of openGL, just wanted to say that code doesn't use classes. From small DirectX 11 experience, I felt that It makes things easier, especially if you have something like model-view-controller. It just gives "visual" separation between components.

Comment: @Incomputable i have done couple of demos by using MVC approach. i will do it to this demo too. thanks a lot for comments.

Comment: Well, one obvious thing is that you should use display lists, for example, rather than direct drawing. Sure, it's not a large amount of drawing, but still, there's hardly a reason to skip display lists, since it's not much extra work.

Comment: @antiHUMAN usually i used buffers and shaders to draw opengl, but havn't done any of fixed function "old school style", display lists is boss i did profile against vbo it beats vao/vbo in my laptop to draw 3d terrain.

Comment: @MORTAL beats VBO's, huh? That's cool. They should have the same performance, I think. But display lists are so easy to use, while VBO's take a bit more messing around. Anyway, there's no reason to use direct drawing, like this. While jus tmessing around, sure, but if you're actually making a game, then try to go for good performance. At the very least it saves electricity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> your scientists were so preoccupied with whether or not they could that they didn't stop to think if they should.

– Dr. Ian Malcolm in *Jurassic Park*

## Use the Tools Available to You

This code exhibits some utterly bizarre constructs that while perfectly legal are so abhorrent I would hope to never see them again in my lifetime. It's hard to know where to begin, so I'll just start from the beginning.

If you're creating constants, make named constants rather than enumerations:

```
const int MINE = 9;
const int TILE_SIZE = 20;
// … etc.
```

The `enum` for `Color` is just fine.

You should use proper named types for variables. The idea of directly declaring (a global!) variable after its anonymous type is pretty awful. For one thing, it means you have to manually type the entire type if you ever want to use it again. You manage not to ever use the type for an RGB value again anywhere in the code, but it's just lurking there waiting for you to need it somewhere. For another it's so unusual that other readers of the code will likely either trip over it or not even notice it because they'll think they couldn't possibly have seen something so bizarre.

In most of your methods you don't change the value of the variables you pass in. In that case, you should mark them as `const` so someone reading your code knows at a glance that the variables will not change.

## Don't Use Global Variables

By using global variables, it becomes very difficult to figure out where they are modified. When they are encapsulated properly in classes you can much more easily understand how the data is modified and by whom. There's a very obvious class structure for this code staring you in the face where most of the globals are declared:

```
class MineSweeper {
public:
    // whatever public methods you need
private:
    cell board[BOARD_SIZE * BOARD_SIZE];
    int death;
    int width;
    int height;
    bool clicked;
    int num_opened;
};
```

All of your `draw` methods could go into a `Render` class, or something similar.

## Simplify

Lots of things in this code seem more complicated than they need to be. You declare what should be a 2-dimensional array as a single dimensional array and then have to write a special function to properly index into it. I have recommended this method myself when there is a performance reason to do it. But with this 9 x 9 game board, there's no reason to do it. Just use a 2-dimensional array:

```
cell board[BOARD_SIZE][BOARD_SIZE];
```

If you do that then the `isOpen()`, `getType()`, `setType()`, and `isFlag()` functions go away.

The `isMine()` function can be simplified to the boundary checks and this line:

```
return (getType(x,y) == MINE);
```

I would personally recommend removing all of the drawing code. It's complicated, uses deprecated OpenGL calls and is inefficient. Instead of drawing things manually with lines and rectangles you should be drawing them with textures.

Your `drawNum()` method is using bare numbers in a case statement that then reads values out of an array. It could be simplified to 3 lines by doing this:

```
void drawNum(int x, int y, int v)
{
    glColor3f(colors[v].r, colors[v].g, colors[v].b);
    glRasterPos2i((x + 0)*TILE_SIZE + PADDING + 6, (y + 0)*TILE_SIZE + PADDING + 5);
    glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_9_BY_15, '0' + v);
}
```